# Accidently replaced '.r' through whole app with '' in flutter project

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I had lots of reference of '.r' through my flutter app and I replaced all '.r' references with '' empty string and I came to to know that dart files also have been modified and now I get these errors in my debug console. I tried to fix these but seems like re-adding '.r' isn't fixing these problems.

**Debug Console:**

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-2.1.3/lib/src/path_provider_windows_real.dart:117:66: Error: Member not found: 'roamingAppData'.

> final String? appDataRoot = await
> getPath(WindowsKnownFolder.roamingAppData);

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-2.1.3/lib/src/path_provider_windows_real.dart:146:60: Error: The method 'rsetGUID' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.

- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/guid.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-3.0.1/lib/src/guid.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'rsetGUID'.

> final Pointer knownFolderID =
> calloc().ref.rsetGUID(folderID);

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-2.1.3/lib/src/path_provider_windows_real.dart:235:5: Error: Expected an identifier, but got '.'.
Try inserting an identifier before '.'.

> ```
> .replaceAll(RegExp(r'[<>:"/\\|?*]'), '_');
> ```

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-2.1.3/lib/src/path_provider_windows_real.dart:237:9: Error: Expected an identifier, but got '.'.
Try inserting an identifier before '.'.

> ```
>   .trimRight();
> ```

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-2.1.3/lib/src/path_provider_windows_real.dart:239:5: Error: Expected an identifier, but got '.'.
Try inserting an identifier before '.'.

> .replaceAll(RegExp(r'[<>:"/\|?*]'), '_');

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 10s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 Exited (sigterm)

Comment: It looks like you made changes in your pub cache, try to run "flutter pub cache repair"

Comment: Deletion failed, path = 'C:\flutter\.pub-cache\_temp' (OS Error: The system cannot find the file specified.
, errno = 2)